# Rendering mixed LTR and RTL text in comments

Tags: bug, android-app

[image]

The handle for the OP of this thread seems to be have characters from a RTL locale. They render very oddly in the comment when mixed with English.

- App Version: 1.0.93
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: VS425PP

  - OS Version: 5.1.1 (161331805d4f5)

Here is another example:

[image]

In Chrome for Android:

[image]

Chrome for Windows:

[image]

Comment: I believe that's Hebrew, not Arabic

Comment: Could you also please provide a link to the comment?

Comment: [Here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105652/what-is-the-origin-of-the-name-jedi/159925#comment421255_159925), my comment seems to be just with the regular RTL problems (question mark on the wrong side) - can you check in it's messed up on the app? (Also, that's Hebrew. Not Arabic - translates to 'light on my nation'.)

Comment: @alexolut The comment has been deleted.

Comment: @Code-Guru I can still see it as of now

Comment: @Riker [The question with the comment which prompted my post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090196/why-do-i-get-a-violation-error) has been deleted, so I cannot load it in the app. The comment itself was also deleted from the question. You must be viewing a cached page or looking at a different comment than the one in my first screenshot.